# spring jsp error

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a simple login form with Spring MVC. I should say that I am new to this.The idea is that I am trying to validate the form (using a class that implements Validator interface) and if something goes wrong tu print the errors.

The validate method is:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) 
{
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "required.username","Va rugam introduceti un nume de utilizator!");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "parola", "required.parola","Va rugam introduceti o parola!");


      User user= (User) target;
      System.out.println(" a:"+user.getUsername()+" b:"+user.getParola());

     User u=userDAO.findByUsername(user.getUsername());


    if(u == null)
    {
        errors.reject("invalid.username","Nume utilizator incorect!");
        //System.out.println("NULL");
    }
    else if(!u.getParola().equals(user.getParola()))
    {
        errors.reject("invalid.parola","Parola incorecta!");


    }
}
```

The problem is with my jsp page :

```
<form:form  method="POST" commandName="user" >
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username :</td>
            <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="invalid.username" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="parola" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="parola" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

If I try to run this I get the error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'invalid' of bean class [pachet.dbo.User]: Bean property 'invalid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

If I delete the line :

```
<td><form:errors path="invalid.username" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

the line

```
 <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error" />
```

shows me the "invalid.username" error,so the error exists..maybe the path isn't right?

Comment: Yea gods, is the preview pane invisible?

Comment: no, it isn't , I just edited the message . Sorry .

Comment: if an answer has worked for you, mark it as accepted. If it helped but the answer is different - add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for rejection:

- reject a particular field (field error)
- reject the whole submission (global error)

You are messing the two:

- `reject(..)` registers a global error, `rejectValue(..)` registers a field error.
- the `path` attribute of `<form:error>` should be a path through the fields of the model attribute. You obviously don't have an `invalid` model attribute. Yours is `user`

The way to fix this is to use:

```
errors.rejectValue("username", "invalid.username", "....");
```

and have:

```
<form:error path="username" .. />
```